# Prevent mobile slide-in menu from being draggable on Dolphin

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, mmenu, dolphin-browser

I am creating a small mobile website, with the menu based on jquery.mmenu, which you can see a demo here: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/index.php

I am facing this small issue where once the menu is open, when using the Dolphin browser, I am able to drag the menu pane around the screen. This does not happen on the default Android browser (I have an old HTC Desire HD). Is there some CSS property I can assign to the menu panel not to make it move around when the user does a drag gesture on Dolphin? Not sure what is causing it to behave like that.

Comment: The browser probably handles overflow: hidden incorrectly. In this case overflow-x I guess.

Comment: Any idea if there is any property to force it to stay in place? Facebook's slide in menu doesn't seem to suffer from the same problem. Thanks!